# MacBook start up problem

Tags: macbook, boot

I have an aging, ailing MacBook. The battery died on it a few months ago, but can still use it when plugged in. I recently upgraded it to Snow Leopard.

Had it unplugged for a few days. Went to boot it up today and now get this symptom:

- start up chime
- white screen with apple logo
- shuts off

That's all it'll do. I tried unplugging and holding down the power button for 30 seconds but that didn't remedy the situation.

Any theories?

Finally an excuse to get the 27" iMac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your hard drive is not working.

Try booting in [verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492). reboot and hit cmd-V

Comment: Hmm...in verbose mode it ends at AppleYukon2. It doesn't shut down...just ends there and never fully boots. BUT...prior to that I'm getting a FSCK FAIL error. So, yep. Looks like the HD.

Comment: Disk repair can't salvage it. Looks like I'm taking the piggy bank to the Apple store.